What is the UK law around buying and selling medications without prescription?
Suppose there is a UK online seller who sells prescription restricted medications without checking that the UK buyer has a prescription. Has the buyer or the seller broken the law? Does it depend on the specific medicine that has been sold?
What about if there is an online international seller who sells UK prescription restricted medications to a UK buyer for delivery. How does the law work here? Will it be enforced in a customs check on the border, in theory?

united-kingdom
Prescription only medicines (POM) are medicines that may be sold or supplied only from a registered pharmacy, or hospital or health centre under the supervision of a pharmacist, in accordance with a prescription issued by a doctor or dentist.
Scenario A:

"a UK online seller who sells prescription restricted medications without checking that the UK buyer has a prescription."

Scenario B:

"an online international seller who sells UK prescription restricted medications to a UK buyer for delivery."

Assuming the UK buyer is buying a POM for their own personal use, they are not breaking the law in either scenario.
In both scenarios the sellers are breaking the law of the UK. The international seller might also be breaking the law of their own country - either because (a) the law requires a prescription to sell a POM or (b) the law wholly forbids distance selling of POM (this is the law in e.g. Spain, Ireland, France).
The relevant UK legislation is The Human Medicines Regulations 2012 (as amended numerous times), specifically PART 12A Sale of medicines to the public at a distance (which refers to other parts of the regulations).

256(B)(1) A person may not sell a medicinal product at a distance to the public by means of information society services unless that person satisfies the following conditions.
...
256(B)(5) Condition D is that where the sale is to a member of the public in the United Kingdom, it is in accordance with regulations 214 (sale or supply of prescription only medicines), 220 (sale or supply of medicinal products not subject to general sale) and 221 (sale or supply of medicinal products subject to general sale).


214.—(1) A person may not sell or supply a prescription only medicine except in accordance with a prescription given by an appropriate practitioner.


"Will [the law] be enforced in a customs check on the border, in theory?"

In theory, yes. In practice, quantities sized for personal use are unlikely to be detected let alone questioned.
See also this BBC report Prescription drugs sold online without robust checks from January 2024.


Has the buyer or the seller broken the law?

Probably (although many firms in the online prescription business purport to have an M.D. in the appropriate jurisdiction who issues prescriptions via telemedicine).

Does it depend on the specific medicine that has been sold?

At a minimum, the punishment under the law would depend upon the specific medicine sold.

What about if there is an online international seller who sells UK
prescription restricted medications to a UK buyer for delivery. How
does the law work here? Will it be enforced in a customs check on the
border, in theory?

Usually, the customs officers would not have any way to know if the medications were mailed pursuant to a prescription or not. If an investigation revealed a pattern and practice of a seller violating U.K. prescription drug laws, however, the appropriate authorities could probably arrange to have a court authorize customs agents intercept these packages.

Usually, the customs officers would not have any way to know if the medications were mailed pursuant to a prescription or not. I do not know about UK, but in Spain drug distribution is heavily regulated. It is not that customs knows or cares if I have a prescription or not; it is that if prescription drugs are sent outside the usual channels, they will be stopped. Or at least that is what I would expect.

If 'probably', do you have a link to the relevant legislation?

"Has the buyer or the seller broken the law?": I think the OP was asking which one of the two have done so. Does your "probably" mean both have broken the law?

@terdon The buyer, the seller, or both., have probably broken the law.

Well yes, but I was curious which if the three, one the other or both, is the case and I assume the OP is as well.
